# Copy a circle of image A into image B

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, gimp

I have two images:

- `a.jpg`
- `b.jpg`

Both images are square (100x100 pixel). I want to cut a circle with a radius of 50 from image `a.jpg` and paste it in the middle of image `b.jpg`. I want to save the result in `c.jpg`.

How can I do this with Linux command line tools? I need to do it within a shell script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many different techniques can be used. ImageMagick has [FX language](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) that can perform complex calculations.

```
convert a.jpg b.jpg -fx 'Wi=w/2; Hi=h/2; hypot(Wi-i, Hi-j) < 50 ? u : v' c.jpg
```

For example...

```
convert -size 100x100 PLASMA: a.jpg
```

[image: a.jpg]

```
convert -size 100x100 GRADIENT:LIME-ORANGE b.jpg
```

[image: b.jpg]

```
convert a.jpg b.jpg -fx 'hypot(50-i, 50-j) < 50 ? u : v' c.jpg
```

[image: c.jpg]

**Update with another technique.**

A faster approach can be leveraging image mask(s) of the shape you wish to crop, and compose/composite it between both images. It'll require a format that supports alpha channels, but only for the initial work. For example...

Create a circle mask, and copy values to alpha channel.

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:White -fill Black \
        -draw 'circle 50 50 50 5' -alpha Copy mask.png
```

[image: mask.png]

```
convert \( a.png mask.png -alpha Set -compose Dst_Out -composite \) \
        b.png -compose Dst_Atop -composite c.png
```

[image: c.png]

Answer (score 1):

Eric's approach is much more succinct, and probably preferable, but here is another way anyway. I am being very environmentally aware and recycling ;-) his start images:

```
magick b.jpg \( a.jpg \( +clone -threshold 101% -fill white -draw "circle 49,49, 49,99"  \) -channel-fx '| gray=>alpha' \) -flatten result.png
```

That says... *"Load `b.jpg` as the background. Load `a.jpg` and then create a transparency mask by cloning the entire `a.jpg` setting it black and drawing a white circle in it and pushing it into the alpha channel. Then flatten that over the top of `b.jpg`"*.

The result is the same as Eric's.